# Silicone or rubber protection for kitchen base

Tags: kitchens, sealing, carpentry

I have been trying to find a solution for a newly installed kitchen. On the base podium of the kitchen, the vendor did not add any rubber flaps or water protection panels to prevent wetting the base when washing the floor.

Is there a simple solution for that? Simple rubber/silicone flap to glue on the base so it doesn't get wet when washing the floor? Thanks?

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps the term you are searching for is "rubber cove molding" or "vinyl cove molding" - a fairly standard product. "Wall base" seems to be another term for it. "resilient" and "thermoplastic" may also be seen where "rubber" is in my first suggestion.

[image: cove base image from floorcity.com]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As for your that area. I assume it being a finish area it looks ugly? IF you have tile I would add a tile baseboard. If not paint it and caulk it. It is important to seal it. This is to prevent water and or food getting under the cracks and creating mildew.

=====
I use to build Starbucks and we were required by the health inspectors to use clear silicon caulking in all areas. It made no difference if it was an area where food was handled, where tables met walls or in your case, baseboards.

The reason for clear is dirt is more noticeable and silicon expands and shrinks much better than painter's caulk. Cheers

Comment: Aren't there any flaps (I wonder what is the professional term for those flaps) like those plastic/silicon flaps used for glass showers or sealing windows, L or T profile shape? As for caulk, I don't like it for 2 reasons: It turns black after a while, and it's not pretty. Caulk as glue, hidden behind a rubber flap is the best solution, but as it, visible, it's not aesthetic.

Comment: I assume you are referring to sealing strips. The problem with those other than not looking cheap is if you do not run a full strip and mend the pieces it will allow water to get under the cabinets and and mildew will thrive and become a health hazard. As for silicon turning black. That is mildew and exactly what you want to prevent and certainly want it noticeable if indeed mildew is thriving. As for silicon not looking pretty, it is clear and not noticeable. Are you thinking of painters caulk which comes in white or black to begin with.